# Selecting index from Cassandra list collection

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, cql3

I was curious if it's possible to SELECT a specific index from a list collection in Cassandra.  Say I have:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  order_list list<text>
);

UPDATE users
   SET ordered_list = [ 'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3' ] WHERE user_id = 'user1';
```

Is it possible to then get back an index of ordered_list, such as ordered_list[1] from a CQL query instead of the entire list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You can `UPDATE` and `DELETE` with subscripts, but not `SELECT` or `INSERT`.